# Always shows NO RESULTS in ASSOCIATE WITH SONAR in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am trying to Configuring SonarQube in Eclipse.It successfully connected to localhost:9000. It does always show `NO RESULTS` while Right click on project -> CONFIGURE -> ASSOCIATE WITH SONAR...

Answer (score 0):

To use SonarQube in Eclipse on a project, it is required that the project has been first analyzed by SonarQube. [See online documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)